# Logitech Mouse stopped working after changing batteries

Tags: logitech-mouse

I just changed batteries for my optical wireless Logitech mouse, but it stopped working; When I put it on, it waits a second and then keeps the green light for few seconds. After that it just stops responding and doesn't show the light even if I'm moving it.

Does this have something to do with batteries? I took new, so they're not empty. And I think it cannot be on batteries, because it keeps the light first, but then just stops responding.

Please help, I would be very very thankfull. This makes me mad to use this mousepad :D

**EDIT:**
Wow, what an fast answer!! Thank you, but you wanted to know this mouse? I think it's Logitech M205, watched from Logitech site, because have not the original package anymore :S

I couldn't find any buttons in receiver, but mouse has button called "reset". Is that the right one?

Comment: yes, try the reset button on the mouse.

Comment: It doesn't effect at all :S

Comment: Have you tried to hold it down for at least 5 seconds?

Comment: Yes but it doesn't help.. When I press it once, it just starts again and keeps green lifght for a while, after that it doesn't responding. If I hold the button, it delays but does the same thing. Could it be broken, because it starts and computer reconizes the receiver but I think that the laser doesn't work, because it should flash the light when regonizing.

Answer (score 3):

Depending on the model of your mouse, there is probably a sync button on the bottom of the mouse, and another sync button on the wireless receiver.  Try pressing one or both of those buttons to get the mouse to reconnect with the receiver.

If you have the specific model name or number of your mouse, please add that to your question for more specific help!

Comment: I recommend that you push the button on the receiver (USB plug) *first* then push the reset button on the mouse.

Comment: Well, there are no buttons in receiver.. Should the mouse flash the light when moved, even if it doesn't connect to receiver?

Answer (score 1):

I had major issues with my M-205 connecting in Windows 7. I took a punt and downloaded the M-305 connection software called Logitech Connection Utility ( the filename is logitech_connect.exe) from the Logitech website. I simply ran it and presto. The M-205 now works!

Answer (score 1):

Try replugging the receiver a few times... I had the same problem and apparently it didn't connect until I tried it for the third or fourth time.. There are no lights on the mouse Logitech M205 when it started working again..

Answer (score 1):

If your Logitech mouse stops responding, especially after you changed the battery, you need to download the Connect Utility from the Logitech website. It will help pair the receiver and the mouse. If all button-pushing, Windows-setting, switching and swearing has no effect this is the way to go. Good luck! HTH.

Answer (score 0):

Alkaline batteries may be at issue.  I've seen "new" alkalines perform poorly and installing lithium batteries solved the problem.

Also, Try unplugging the receiver from the computer and then replugging it.

Comment: Well I tried both of these, but didn't work :( I'm desperate, should the green light appear when moving mouse even if it's not connected to receiver? Should the receiver have some kind of sync button?

Comment: Have you tried your mouse in very close proximity to the receiver (less than 6 inches)?  This obviously isn't a fix but it would help for troubleshooting.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try cleaning the contacts of where the battery sits with some rubbing alcohol. If this mouse is a few years old, the contacts could be dirty and not allowing electricity to easily flow.

If all else fails, call logitech support and they may replace it. I had a G5 wired mouse die recently and they replaced it for free. Just make sure you have the serial number located before you call to make life easier for the service tech.